# What do we call this small area in integration in math?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

[image]

In the above image we can see to find area of circle they consider the very small annulus with area of $\delta A=2\pi r \delta r$. and in order to to find $\int u^3dA$ and it plugged in equation of $u_r$ into integral.

My question is :  We consider the $\delta A$  as area of annulus and find the integral with bound $r\in [0,R]$. which give the area of circle. I wonder what we call this small area $\delta A$ in math? Is this riemenn?

Comment: $\delta A$ is the infinitesimal area enclosed between circles of radii $r$ and $r+\delta r$. Instead of differentiating, you might as well find it by $\delta A = \pi (r+\delta r)^2 - \pi r^2  = \pi (\delta r)^2  + 2\pi r\delta r \approx 2\pi r\delta r$. Here, we choose to neglect the higher order (second and larger) terms.

Comment: Also, yes, this is a Riemann sum.

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine . I understood. thank you very much for making it clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That kind of quantity is known as a differential.

Basically, a differential of a quantity-A dependent on another quantity-B is the amount of increase of quantity-A as we nudge a little of quantity B i.e: a relation between increments.

This video discusses it [see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5PS4cMWAWo&list=PLKc2XOQp0dMwj9zAXD5LlWpriIXIrGaNb&index=22&ab_channel=PennOnlineLearning)